# How are these questions (about the relation of the self to the body and soul) not duplicates?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, exact-duplicates, flagging

I flagged [Am I a body with a soul or a soul with a body?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66723/am-i-a-body-with-a-soul-or-a-soul-with-a-body) as a duplicate of [Is the "I" consciousness from the body or from the soul](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30623/is-the-i-consciousness-from-the-body-or-from-the-soul). I don't see any substantive difference between the two. It doesn't appear that anyone actually voted to close it, though my auto-generated comment got four upvotes. The flag was declined when [a mod voted to leave the question open](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/review/close/21789).

So my question is, what is it about the two questions that makes them distinct? Shouldn't one be closed as a duplicate?

Comment: I agree that there's a lot of overlap, but I think we shouldn't be quick to close similar questions. A duplicate should be an exact copy, not just very similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I'm the mod you refer to, the one who decided "leave open" on the review, let me explain why I did so.

The newer question is about one's self. In short, what am I, a body or a soul?

The older question is about one's "I"-consciousness, or sense of self. In short, where does my sense of "I" come from, my body or my soul?

So they're not duplicates.

Comment: So, the difference is "self" vs. "sense of self." Is that correct? If so, that's a very subtle distinction, and one that I doubt was intended by the OPs of the question.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude, that's how I read (redd) them and read (reed) them still. They seem to me to be completely different questions.

Comment: I guess this is subjective, but it looks to me like the answers on both questions are interchangeable, and that one's "sense of self" would necessarily derive from one's "self," but we'll see what the community thinks.

Comment: Hm, it seems the answerers to the older question disagree with me: they all seem to read it as having asked about one's self and not one's sense of self (despite the wording of the question). (Unless I'm not understanding the answers.) So perhaps you're right that they should be combined (into the newer, clearer one, probably). In any event, this answer is an accurate description of why I decided "leave open".